# Extend storage on PC

Tags: hard-drive

I have a PC with a 256GB SSD, that I would like to replace with a new 512GB SSD.

My laptop has only one slot so I cannot make an extension.

What is the best way to copy/clone all current information (OS, programs, data..) from my 256 SSD to the 512 SSD, so I keep the current state of my computer with extended storage space ?

- Windows 7 64bits
- Two partitions C and D.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just clone the drive then create/extend the partitions how you want them.  You will require a USB 2.5" enclosure to do this

Comment: Will copying the contents of the drive (file per file) work? ie will the new SSD be bootable?

Comment: @jidma, unfortunately, straight file copies do not make drives bootable :(

Comment: @Fazer87 yep that's what I thought, and hence my question :) thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While we generally don't do software recommendations here, [This page](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1844976/clone-drive-partitions.html) has a post which links to several software solutions which can be used to clone entire drives with multiple partitions.